# jQuery UI breaks when clicking on draggable element: "Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined"

Tags: magento2, template, jquery, requirejs

I'm using Ultimo theme and created a child theme. I created a custom module that uses jQuery UI draggable. When the page loads it's all fine but when I click on an element that should be able to be dragged, the console gives an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined ..... jquery.js:6702

Seems like it is conflicting with jQuery but I have no clue how to fix it, even after reading numerous posts about problems similar to this.

How can I fix this error?

requirejs-config.js @ app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend

```
var config = {
    map: {
        jqueryui: 'Vendor_Module/js/jquery-ui.min'
    }
};
```

drag.js file @ app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Makes the pieces draggable & sets options
        $("#piecesArea > div > img").draggable({
            //Makes it so that the pieces' z-index can be reordered
            stack: { group: '#piecesArea > div > img', min: 500,scroll: false },
            distance: 0
        });

        // Sets what happens when you release a piece
        $("#roomArea").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui){
                // This is so that the element "sticks" even when tab is changed.
                ui.draggable.addClass("draggedout");
            },
            // Changes current tab to the tab the piece belongs to when dragged out of body area
            out: function(event, ui){
                ui.draggable.removeClass("draggedout");
                var whichTab = ui.draggable.parent().attr("id");
                $("#piecesArea").tabs('select' , whichTab);
            }
        });

        // Tabs
        $("#piecesArea").tabs();

        // Changes the body when thumbnails are clicked
        $("#swatchesArea a").click( function() {
            var changeSrc = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#roomArea>img").attr("src", changeSrc);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

default.xml @ app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <link src="Vendor_Module::js/drag.js"/>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/mainstylesheet.css"/>
  </head>
  <body/>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few potential issues with this:

1. There is no need to add jQuery UI to your require JS config, it's
   already included with M2. Just use `jquery/ui` as a
   dependency.
2. You should use `domReady!` as a dependency rather than
   `$(document).ready`. Like so: `require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui',
   'domReady!'], function($, ui, doc){`
3. You're loading your script via require and XML at the same time. You
   only need to add your script once via Require JS, once you have done
   this there is no need to include your JS via XML to. This is likely
   your issue.

To rule out any issues with your logic does the code work outside of Magento?

This is one method of calling a JS file from your template:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/js/drag": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes the script works flawless outside Magento. The script was originally made by someone else to be a dollmaker eg. a dress up game for kids. I just converted it to be able to use it in Magento.

Comment: It sounds like it is related to how you're loading the scripts, what happens when you try the above?

Comment: I've editted the files like you said in point 1 and 2. I'm not clear on your 3rd point tho. I removed the loading via XML. I added my script via Require JS, and called it "drag". How does my template file know it can use drag.js to do it's magic

Comment: I presumed the require js block was in your template sorry, you can call it using either `x-magento-init` or `data-mage-init`. I've added one method to my answer, full details can be found on http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html.

Comment: I added your calling method in my template file but it throws an error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 7. Looking at the console the error is at: // components initialised on the element defined by selector

Comment: Try the updated version I've added, all you'll need to do is replace the location to your JS file.

Comment: Updated the code to your method but it still gives the error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined. maybe you can check for yourself at https://www.topgrepen.nl/showroom

Comment: I have to add that after like a dozen page refreshes the code partially works because the tabs start working. so maybe it is just a conflict with another library

Comment: Possibly, if it is a conflict I'd suspect it's either related to the Magento 2 tabs or the jQuery UI version of Magento 2. To test these you can try removing the tabs section of your code, and overwriting the M2 version of jQuery UI.

Comment: Everything from the script works except the tabs part. I've been reading about conflicts with prototype but all are loose ends

Comment: The tabs are showing now but their contents are all beneath the tabs